# Can syphilis be transmitted by kissing the lips, licking the throat, touching vagina with finger?

Tags: syphilis

tow day ago I kissed the lips of my gf and licked her throat. she had no sore on her face or throat.also I touched her pussy for a sex with my finger because it was very wet i pull it back.if she has syphilis is it possible that I might be infected?I am so worried please help me

Comment: she had no sore on her vagina too

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: Her wetness was normal. It indicates she was aroused.

Answer (score 2):

Syphilis is transmitted from person to person by direct contact with a syphilitic sore, known as a chancre. Chancres can occur on or around the external genitals, in the vagina, around the anus , or in the rectum, or in or around the mouth. Transmission of syphilis can occur during vaginal, anal, or oral sex.

See more here:

https://www.cdc.gov/std/syphilis/stdfact-syphilis-detailed.htm